# Python pass filepath to another function

Tags: python, function, tkinter, filepath

I can't seem to figure out how to pass `user_filepath` global onto my second function. What can I change to do this? I'm using these two functions in a GUI. I try passing it to `split_lines()` but that isn't working saying `user_filepath` is not defined. Could I have some insight onto how to correct this? I'm new with tkinter and handling filepaths.

```
class Sequence_Class:
"This holds the functions for the button sequence."
global user_filepath

def open_file(): # Defines the function that opens the user's file in specific location.
    user_filepath = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")])
    if not user_filepath:
        return
    txt_edit.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    with open(user_filepath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
        text = input_file.read()
        txt_edit.insert(tk.END, text)
    window.title(f"Linestring Compiler V1.0 - {user_filepath}")

# Defines the function that reads, delimits and quantifies the data.
def split_lines(user_filepath, delimiter, remove = '^[0-9.]+$'):
    for line in user_filepath:
        tokens = line.split(delimiter)
        tokens = [re.sub(remove, "", token) for token in tokens]
        clean_list = list(filter(lambda e:e.strip(), tokens))
    txt_edit.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    with open(user_filepath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
        clean_list = input_file.read()
        txt_edit.insert(tk.END, clean_list)

def save_file(): # Defines the function that saves the open file to a new location.
    filepath = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".txt", filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")],)
    if not filepath:
        return
    with open(filepath, mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as output_file:
        text = txt_edit.get("1.0", tk.END)
        output_file.write(text)
...

btn_compile = tk.Button(frm_buttons, text="Compile Lines", command=Sequence_Class.split_lines(user_filepath, "/"))
```

Comment: you can use `global` keyword here.

Comment: How would I go about that? I tried, however I couldn't figure out how to call that global in my second function

Comment: The design of your functions needs a rework. You should either create a class with a file path as attribute, which makes it accessible to all methods, or your functions should take a file path as parameter and act on that.

Answer (score 1):

Just define filepath at the global level.

```
filepath = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Text Files", "*.txt"), ("All Files", "*.*")])

def open_file():
    file_path = filepath
    if not filepath:
        return
    txt_edit.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    with open(filepath, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
        text = input_file.read()
        txt_edit.insert(tk.END, text)
    window.title(f"Linestring Compiler V1.0 - {filepath}")

lines = filepath
def split_lines(lines, delimiter, remove = '^[0-9.]+$'):
    for line in lines:
        tokens = line.split(delimiter)
        tokens = [re.sub(remove, "", token) for token in tokens]
        clean_list = list(filter(lambda e:e.strip(), tokens))
        cleaned_data.append(clean_list)
    txt_edit.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    with open(input_file, mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as input_file:
        text = input_file.read()
        txt_edit.insert(tk.END, text)
```

It looks like there are some redundant variables, like file_path and lines. You might want to open the file in the global scope and manipulate it in your functions instead of opening it in both functions.

Comment: Thank you, I tried including the `global` call for filepath, then use that in my other function `split_lines()` but i'm getting an error that `filepath` is not defined? Do I need to call `lines = filepath` in order to use my second function?

Comment: My apologies, this solution is wrong. Correcting now.

Comment: Hi @rangeseeker, will this work the same if I use the global within a class?

Comment: A class will be able to access a global variable.